# encountered an issue where the modifications made to the style-m.css and style-l.css files are not being reflected on the website

Tags: magento2, css, less-css, styles, less-compilation

After the installation of the Martfury Magento theme on my server, we attempted to make changes to these two files but were unable to locate them within the theme directory. I found these files in,

/pub/static/frontend/MageBig/martfury_layout01/en_US/css/**styles-m.css**
/pub/static/frontend/MageBig/martfury_layout01/en_US/css/**styles-l.css**

Unfortunately, the modifications made to these files have not been successfully reflected on my website. when I run static content deploy command the changes has gone.so, what I can do to save these changes permanantly to my website ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make any changes to any files that are in the `/pub/static` folder, since these are auto generated, and your changes will be lost.

If you need to make CSS changes, you can modify one of your themes CSS files, and add your styles at the end, for example.

The themes CSS files are probably located in:

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/web/css
```

Comment: Can I copy and paste styles from styles-m.css file ? can you give me an example please ?